# Upgrade to 13.10 failed

Tags: upgrade

Did the upgrade, after the downloads it started the upgrade, then stopped at the "downloading Flash"..  It stopped there for over an hour so I had no choice but to shut it down. Now when it boots there is no top bay with the time, shutdown etc, Ubuntu Software installer etc will not run..   How do I fix it without losing all my installed apps and settings?

Comment: Have you tried to run the upgrade again. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I haven't done as in its current state it can't connect to the wifi for internet access, any further suggestions?

Comment: One way is to trying to connect to wi-fi from your terminal and doing the everything up from there. Or get an alternative ubuntu 13.10 image and make an usb and and upgrade from that. [ubuntu alternative-downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed, didn't realise the downloads had completed except for flash, so sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade started the fix, then all was well. Again, thanks heaps.

Comment: how did you manage to get the internet working